# Remove space and hypen at the beginning of string in java

Tags: java, regex, string

I want to remove the leading whitespace and hypen from a string:

```
String s = " – Direktorat Jenderal Pajak";
```

I want the result to be like:

```
s = "Direktorat Jenderal Pajak";
```

Comment: `s = s.substring(3);`

Comment: `s.replace("–","").trim();`

Comment: what is the regex for this string "VIVA.co.id – " ?

Comment: Regex replace `^\s*?-\s*` with empty string `""`

Answer (score 0):

If all the lines have **exactly three** characters as indicated (a space followed by a hyphen followed by a space), the response of 4castle is true and it's the **fastest** way to do that (s = s.substring(3);).
However if there can be an arbitrary number of spaces and hyphens, you have to use regular expression with s.replaceFirst("regexp", "") like this:

```
String target = s.replaceFirst("[ ]*[–]*[ ]*" , "");
```

Explanation of regular expression used:

[ ] (1 space) : mean simply one space

[ ]* : mean arbitrary number of spaces (0..any number)

[–]* : mean any number of hyphens

At the end of the day, the all regular expression used mean: replace any number of spaces **followed by** any number of hyphens **followed by** any number of spaces at the lead of line (replaceFirst) by empty string.

Comment: These brackets are obsolete, `" *-* *"` would do the same. But `replaceFirst` does not ensure that the match is at the beginning of the string, so you need the anchor `^` at the beginning of the pattern.

Comment: @Holger I agree for ^ to enforce processing but the use of replaceFirst is sufficient in this problem context. brackets is not obsolote but it's a different and more rigorous syntax. regular expression has several syntaxes as you should know.

Comment: Well, *if* you use `^`, then `replaceFirst` is sufficient. Without it, it is not. Since removing the bracket yields the same result, they *are* obsolete. And they are *not* a “more rigorous syntax”. They denote character classes rather than the single character that is actually intended.